# Using GROUP BY and returning all criteria matching records

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores various types of flags. Each flag type has a reasonId column. So you could flag a post as spam and use several reasons; as abusive and use several reasons, etc.

I need a query to return *all* spam flags (flagTypeId=1) on a single post and, in addition, an extra column to return the number of times a flag reason occurred (reasonId). I need the full record set because I need to tack the user data, thus returning a grouped result is not sufficient by itself:

Assuming I have a `flags` table with `PK id`, `int flagTypeId`, `int postId`, `int reasonId`, and `userId`, I wrote this:

```
SELECT id, flagTypeId, postId, userId, reasonId, COUNT(reasonId) reasonCount
FROM flags
WHERE flagTypeId = @flagTypeId AND postId = @postId
GROUP BY reasonId
ORDER BY reasonCount DESC
```

This query does not return the correct number of records. If I have four spam records, and two of those four share the same reasonId, only three records come back. I want all four records to come back with an extra column showing the number of times a reasonId occurred.

Any ideas how I can modify my query to achieve this?

**SAMPLE INPUT/OUTPUT**

Assuming three peope flagged the same post, and two of them used the same flag reason.

```
id    flagTypeId    postid    reasonid    userid    count
1     1             1         1           1         2
2     1             1         1           2         2
3     1             1         2           3         1
```

Comment: Why do you need it to display the count AND display the multiple records? That seems redundant.

Comment: @Sam DeHaan, I need to determine the most frequently occurring reason. Is there a better way?

Comment: What I mean is that showing count=2 AND showing the record twice is confusing/redundant. Getting back three records if two of your four have == reasonId should be *good*, I would think.

Comment: @Sam DeHaan, because I omitted a userId column. I need info on the flaggers. So that would be a differenciating column.

Comment: So, if you `GROUP BY reasonId, userId`, does that give you the results you want?

Comment: @Sam DeHaan, no it does not. I need *all* flags. Then I need to determine how many times a flag reason occurred. I will use all the records to get info on the flaggers, and the reasonIdCount to report the most popular reason a post was flagged for.

Comment: @Sam DeHaan, to give you an idea, look at StackOverFlow's flagging/closing system: They use the most frequent vote reason to display a message: "This post was closed because ...."; but they still need to collect information on each individual voter who voted to close a question. Thus a count as you suggested does not work. I hope I made myself clearer now.

Comment: I'm still having some trouble understanding what you're trying to extract from the data. Can you provide sample data and sample output?

Comment: @Sam DeHaan, see my above comment on StackOverFlow. Basically, they need data on ALL voters. This answers the requirement for getting all records. Then they need to work out the most frequently occurring vote reason. This answers the requirement for a count. This way, if two people out of four people flagged the same post for the same reason, you would still get each voter's data, and the correct count.

Comment: @sam, What I am trying to say, in short, if you use GROUP BY as I did, you will lose the flagger data. All flaggers who used the same flag reason would be bunched in the same record.

Comment: @Sam, this is redundant now, I will not rely on MySQL to do this for me. But I did provide the sample so you could see what I mean. Notice the `count` col reflects the total number of times a reasonid was used. So reasonId 1 was cast by two users, hence the count col says 2. I don't think this is particularly complicated or a strange requirement, to be honest. You're just having a hard time to see it's utility. Just take my word for it, it has utility as I explained above.

Comment: It's much easier to understand once you put the userID back in there, I think the lack of that was what threw me off. Thanks for clarifying even after you decided to not use SQL for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going about it a little backwards.  Keep in mind that, if you're already retrieving all the information in a collection of records, you already have the count of records, just by getting the size of the returned collection.

Tweak your query to remove the GROUP BY clause and COUNT column.  Then, assuming it was something like PHP, and you fetched the results of the modified query into an array `$flagReasons`, you can just reference `count($flagReasons)` to get the count.

Comment: I think you are right. I just thought there was an easier way to do it before resorting to application server code.

Answer (score 2):

Would this work:

```
SELECT id, flagTypeId, postId, flags.reasonId, x.reasonCount
FROM 
    flags
        JOIN (SELECT reasonid, COUNT(*) AS reasonCount FROM flags WHERE flagTypeId = @flagTypeId AND postId = @postId GROUP BY reasonid) AS X 
        ON flags.reasonid = x.reasonid
WHERE 
    flagTypeId = @flagTypeId AND postId = @postId
```

Comment: it does. I just didn't know it would be that complicated. I think Sean is right. It's not worth the agro in trying to do it in MySQL. Thanks!